# HTTP PUT method returns error not found

Tags: javascript, json, angular, html-table, put

I got an error when trying to do PUT method. The error is like this: 
`PUT http://localhost:3000/Student/ 404 (Not Found)`

Here is a snippet from stock.service.ts file

```js
updStudent(id: string, newName: string, newYear: string, newSemester: string, newScore: string): Observable<any>
    {
        console.log(JSON.stringify({
            name: newName, 
            year: newYear, 
            semester: newSemester,
            score: newScore
        }));
        return this.http.put("http://localhost:3000/Student/", +id,
        JSON.stringify({
                name: newName, 
                year : newYear, 
                semester : newSemester,
                score: newScore
            }));
     }
```

And here is a snippet from app.component.ts file

```js
selectedStudent: any;

updStudent(Id: string, newName: string, newYear: string, newSemester: string, newScore: string)
  {
    this.stockService.updStudent(this.selectedStudent.Id, newName, newYear, newSemester, newScore).subscribe(

      data =>
      {
        this.getAllStocks();
      }

    );
    console.log('here', Id , newName, newYear, newSemester, newScore);
  }
```

Can anyone help me with this error? Please let me know if more snippets are needed. Thank you.

[Link full ts](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1k7C1LI5GJFKYmFteOwJp3Fu2jlAreixd)

Comment: Can you change `http;//localhost:3000/Student/` to `http://localhost:3000/Student/`? (Note the `;` and `:`)

Comment: Where is the http://localhost:4200 coming from?

Comment: I have no idea either where is localhost:4200 came from

Comment: changed `;` to `:`

Comment: So... does it works?

Comment: Still got error `PUT http://localhost:3000/Student/ 404 (Not Found)`. I will edit my post.

Comment: The problem is, you don't have that service running?

Comment: But the post(add) and delete method works just fine

Comment: your service must be configured for some other method and not PUT. Share the code for the service

Comment: Can you share your code for `POST` and `DELETE` as well? If the url is correct, `PUT` should encounter 405 Method Not Allowed instead of 404 Not Found

Comment: here is a link for servis.ts file www.goo.gl/Leajix

Comment: do u have api to handle put request?

Answer (score 1):

Api which is being called don't support Put() call. You should use Post Method call

```
updStudent(id: string, newName: string, newYear: string, newSemester: string, newScore: string): Observable<any>
    {
        console.log(JSON.stringify({
            name: newName, 
            year: newYear, 
            semester: newSemester,
            score: newScore
        }));
        return this.http.post("http;//localhost:3000/Student/", +id,
        JSON.stringify({
                name: newName, 
                year : newYear, 
                semester : newSemester,
                score: newScore
            }));
     }
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but i already have post and delete methods that work just fine.